# Get image from folder and put in phpBB page using JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, phpbb

I am trying to get a jpg image from a folder and put it into a div when the page loads using javascript. I would like to use JQuery if possible. So far I have this that works if wrapped as a function and I press a link on the page that calls that function but I would rather it just load as soon as the page is ready without having to press the link

```
<dd>
<div id="videothumbnail{attach_row.ASSOC_INDEX}" name="videothumbnail{attach_row.ASSOC_INDEX}" id="videothumbnail{attach_row.ASSOC_INDEX}"></div><a href="javascript:insertvideothumbnail{attach_row.ASSOC_INDEX}()">View Thumbnail</a>
<a href="javascript:insertnewvideothumbnail('{attach_row.ASSOC_INDEX}')">View Thumbnail</a>
</dd>

<script>
// <![CDATA[
function insertvideothumbnail{attach_row.ASSOC_INDEX}(){
var code ="<img id=\"videothumbnail{attach_row.ASSOC_INDEX}\" src=\"{attach_row.VIDEOTHUMBNAIL}\" width=\"200px\" />";
document.getElementById("videothumbnail{attach_row.ASSOC_INDEX}").innerHTML = code;
}

// ]]>
</script>
```

Also does anyone know of a script that is available which generates thumbnails from a video using ffmpeg and displays them on a page so that a user can select the thumbnail they want to represent the video? this is what I eventually want to accomplish.

Comment: A point isn't clear (at least to me) : Why don't you simply use the html img element ?

Comment: omit the `// <![CDATA[` unless you are really writing xhtml/xml.

Comment: `<img src="" alt="" />` Simple. Not sure why you're over complicating this.

Comment: I just wanted to learn how to do this so I can then go on and try to make a script that can create another thumbnail using ffmpeg and show it to the user without having to leave the page.

Comment: I edited my message above to show the code that does work. The problem with this is that I have to press 'view thumbnail'. Now I want it to just load the image when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a callback function to the `DOM ready` event using jQuery like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var code ="<img id=\"videothumbnail{attach_row.ASSOC_INDEX}\" src=\"{attach_row.VIDEOTHUMBNAIL}\" width=\"200px\" />";
    document.getElementById("videothumbnail{attach_row.ASSOC_INDEX}").innerHTML = code;
});
```

Comment: I tried that before I posted this message but it doesn't seem to work. Thanks for letting me know I was on the right track though. Now I just need to work out why the image doesn't show up.

Comment: I examined the page source after adding your suggested code and this is what I get, as you can see no image element is being put in the div - 'code' <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var code ="<img id=\"videothumbnail0\" src=\"http://www.mysite.net/forumtest/resources/file/22045?ft=1\" width=\"200px\" />";
document.getElementById("videothumbnail0").innerHTML = code; // Looks for the html element and inserts above code
});
</script>
<div id="videothumbnail0" name="videothumbnail0"></div>

Comment: @HTML5Noob If you mean the 'View Source' option in browsers then that simply shows you the HTML that was returned from the server; it doesn't include any additions made by Javascript once the page has been loaded. Use Firebug or another debugging tool to inspect the actual state of the element.

Comment: I also just noticed that you're attempting to create an `<img>` element with the same ID as the container `<div>` that it's supposed to be within. IDs are supposed to be unique for the page, so that's not going to produce valid HTML.

Comment: ok. Just to let you know I edited my original message to show the code that does work. Why the answers here aren't working has me stumped. I tried changing var code ="TEST"; and it still doesnt put anything in the div. Is this something that happens with phpBB only?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scan a directory and list all the jpg images in that folder, you can use this script (images.php):

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('images/')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if (!in_array($entry, array(".", "..") && is_numeric(strpos(".jpg", $entry)))) {
            echo "<img src=\"$entry\" alt=\"\" />\n";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

After that get the output from this PHP and update it in the DOM using jQuery AJAX.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'images.php',
    success: function(data) {
        $('.result').html(data);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: No, that's not what they want to do at all. Actually read the question before answering.

Comment: Sorry but, you can get this via jQuery AJAX and populate inside the DIV after the page loads right? I have updated the code. See if that helps.

Comment: They already know the URL of the image, they just want to add it to a `<div>` element. Also, the idea of submitting an AJAX request on page load seems inherently wrong to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document.ready(function(){
        $('videothumbnail{attach_row.ASSOC_INDEX}')
        .append('<img id="videothumbnail{attach_row.ASSOC_INDEX}" src="{attach_row.VIDEOTHUMBNAIL}" width="200px" />');
    }));
```